# Can I specify the email location to send to?

Tags: email

In both CiviMail and when creating an Email activity, I can specify the contact recipient(s), but the recipient email address is always that contact's Primary email address.

Instead, I want to specify "send to Billing email" or "send to Home email". Is that possible out of the box, or is there a suitable workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already do this with CiviMail. It can be found behind the wrench icon next to the recipient selection:

[image: Use email locations]

Answer (score 1):

With an email activity you send an email to a non-primary address by going to the contact summary tab and hovering over the other email address and then clicking. But I can't see a more systematic way of sending to another category of address in CiviMail. Seems to rather defeat the purpose of having the different categories of address. Perhaps some specific functionality picks up the billing address, but I can't see how some of the others might be used!